# It is too slow to update the like attribute to algolia db, how do I speed it up?

Tags: reactjs, backend, algolia, instantsearch.js

I have an attribute named like on each hit for my index. Whenever I click the like button, I have to wait for a long time until everything is all set. Is there a way I can speed up the process?

I have already tried waiting three steps. First, I will get the object using getObject. Second, I will do partialUpdate to update the likes attr. Last, I will wait using waitTask until everything is settle down.

```
router.patch("/likes/:id", auth.required, async (req, res) => {
  const increment = req.body.liked ? -1 : 1;

  try {
    const content = await index.getObject(req.params.id, ["likes"]);

    //Because the aync feature of algolia
    //We have to waittask for its update to keep consistency
    await index.partialUpdateObject(
      {
        likes: content.likes + increment,
        objectID: req.params.id
      },
      (err, { taskID } = {}) => {
        index.waitTask(taskID, err => {
          if (!err) {
            return res.json({ message: "updated" });
          }
        });
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

I want to speed up the process. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This basically the waiting time for the response to come back from the Back-side.
The job may need to be done from the Back-side to reduce the request->response time.

If you only controlling this issue from Front-end, There is an approach to be used, it's currently used by major companies like **Facebook** for example, abd it's much better for **UX**.

**Therotically:**

- A user hits the like button.
- You update the like button as it's already been liked!
- You send the request to perform like operation in your database to save it.
- Response comes back with two possible results:

  1. **Success:** thus, there is no more job to do.
  2. **Failure:** You remove the like, pop-up a message or something to tell the user that something wrong happened and he may try again or something.

I hope giving this approach will help you fix this problem.